# Find GOP size for mpeg4 video file

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, bmp, aforge

I am working on mpeg4 video file and I'm using AForge.Video.FFMPEG to extract all frames in video as bitmap images, i use container .mp4 coded with mpeg4.

I need to use only I-frame for each GOP, is there any method or location to find the GOP in mpeg4 use C#?

Comment: What kind of container? MP4 file? Or MPEG-4 file in, e.g., AVI or MKV? Many formats carry extra information to show where the I-frames live.

Comment: @Multimedia Mike/.mp4 file that coded with mpeg4

Comment: Are you counting on this AForge framework to also decode the video data? Or can you extract and decode through another path? Reading through the AForge docs, it doesn't look like it allows you to identify just the I-frames. However, it's pretty straightforward to manually pluck the I-frames out of .mp4 file, if you're up to the task. You just have to have a way to decode them afterwards.

Comment: I read each frame in video as bitmap ,then .mp4 convert to sequence of bitmap ,how can i find I-frame ??

Comment: You can parse the moov header in the MP4 file and locate the video track's stss atom (sync samples). This is a table of all the sync samples (I-frames). Then, find the video track's chunk offset table (either stco or co64 atom) in order to locate the I-frames' absolute file offsets.